# Django model form validation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to only take input of A or B from HTML Form I create...
But this one did not work.
I have tried if type is not 'A' or 'B' or using !=.. nothing worked.
What is the right code for it?

**forms.py**

```
class YamlForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Form_info
    fields = '__all__'
    # fields = ['name', 'type', 'vlan_id', 'rdp', 'ip_master', 'ip_backup', 'vip', 'nat_ip', 'cidr', 'dns', 'dhcp', 'dhcp_pool_start', 'dhcp_pool_end']
    widgets = {
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'name', 'name': 'name'}),
        'vlan_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'vlan_id', 'name': 'vlan_id'}),
        'rdp': forms.Select(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES),
        'dhcp':forms.Select(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES)
    }
    error_messages = {
        'name': {
            'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
        },
    }


def clean_type(self):
        type = self.cleaned_data['type']
        if not 'A' or 'B':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter A or B")


        return type


def clean_vlan_id(self):
        vlan_id = self.cleaned_data.get('vlan_id')
        if vlan_id not in range(1300, 1899):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Pleanse enter the right # in range")

        return vlan_id
```

**my HTML**

```
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="type">TYPE:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <span class="text-danger" small>{{ form.type.errors }}</span>
      {{ form.type }}

  </div>
```

Comment: `if not 'A' or 'B':` is this really what's in your code ?

Comment: Yeah.. the thing is I can only validate one either A or B but cant do both using or condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with Django, but purely with Python.

```
if not 'A' or 'B':
```

won't evaluate to what you expect. Instead when you want to compare a variable on multiple values use this syntax:

```
if type not in {'A','B'}:
```

Note that I used a `set` be cause it has a faster look-up time than other data structures like `list`.

Comment: Omg it worked... Thank yo so much. You saved my day :)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? If I wanted to make the range of 1300-1899 and 2300-2649, I used range but it won't work :( sorry I will edit it. I am new here

Comment: You can, but I can't understand what you just wrote.

Comment: so i edited another def up there. so I am giving a range of 1300-1899 and 2300-2649 from my user input on HTML form.. in this case should I use separate if statement? even my first if statement wont work when I used the range syntax

Comment: Since these ranges are not a single value like 'A' or 'B'.. I am not sure if I can use set like you did before.. I don't know how to express ranges in #.

Comment: @Angie try `if (vlan_id not in range(1300, 1899)) or (vlan_id not in range(2300, 2649))` Also, if `vlan_id` is a string make sure to cast it before comparing it `int(vlan_id)`

Comment: Also, take a look at [`.isDigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) to make sure the cast won't fail.

Comment: Sadly.. It won't work :( It always gives me an error message of please enter the right # in range.. I made sure I did casting of int(vlan_id)

Comment: What do you enter in the `vlan_id` ?

Comment: any number between 1300-1899 or 2300-2649. those are valid input from users :)

Comment: if not (int(vlan_id) in range(1300, 1899) or int(vlan_id) in range(2300, 2649)): this fixed my problem! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Angie isn't what I said ?? haha